Basic question about measuring an expectation value of a Hermitian observable
For a pure 1-qubit state $\alpha \lvert 0 \rangle + \beta \lvert 1 \rangle$, measuring the expectation value of the Pauli Z operator can be understood as counting the occurrences of +1 or -1 based on whether we observe $\lvert 0 \rangle \langle 0 \rvert$ or $\lvert 1 \rangle \langle 1 \rvert$, where the probabilities are determined by $\alpha^2$ and $\beta^2$.
For a more general mixed state $\rho$, can we similarly interpret this as counting the occurrences of +1 or -1 depending on whether we observe $\lvert 0 \rangle \langle 0 \rvert$ or $\lvert 1 \rangle \langle 1 \rvert$, with the probabilities now given by $\langle 0 \rvert \rho \lvert 0 \rangle$ and $\langle 1 \rvert \rho \lvert 1 \rangle$? More generally, for an observable $O$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, can we extend this idea to summing or subtracting the eigenvalues based on the sampling probability $\langle \psi_i \rvert \rho \lvert \psi_i \rangle$, where $\lvert \psi_i \rangle$ are the corresponding eigenvectors? But these probabilities don't necessarily sum up to $1$, do they? When we try to numerically run this simulation, does this imply that we need to normalize the probability?

Yes, this is exactly how you should interpret a measurement observable.
However, in the more general case the probabilities really do sum to 1. One of the defining properties of a density matrix is that
$$
\text{Tr}(\rho)=1=\sum_i\langle\psi_i|\rho|\psi_i\rangle
$$
where $|\psi_i\rangle$ is any orthonormal basis, such as the spectral basis of any operator (you just have to be careful about how you deal with degeneracy to ensure that all the eigenvectors are orthonormal within a degenerate subspace).
